# AngularJS Как вставить переменную в выражение паттерна?

Tags: angularjs, шаблоны-проектирования

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="pattern" ng-model="val" required>
```

JS. Паттерн - 3 числа через запятую

```
function interpreterCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pattern = /^(\d+,){2}\d+$/;
  // $scope.num=2;
  // $scope.pattern = /^(\d+,){$scope.num}\d+$/;
}
```

Как в выражение `{2}` подставить свою переменную?

[пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/lye7La5DKWoGttDaSnzL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует воспользоваться конструктором RegExp для создания объекта регулярного выражения:

```
var num = 2;
$scope.pattern = new RegExp("^(\\d+,){" + num + "}\\d+$");
```

P.S. http://javascript.ru/regexp